# Reset phpmyadmin username password centos 6

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, centos

I forgot my Phpmyadmin username and password, installed phpmyadmin long time ago and I forgot those login credentials now what should I do to get it back? The server is running centos 6, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: did you check this? https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=47080

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to reset the PHPMyAdmin password. Either you can change the MySQL root user password and login to PHPMyAdmin console using the username "root" and corresponding password or you can reset the login details by finding the PHPMyAdmin installation path and edit "config.inc.php" using any suitable editor.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = ''
```